# JavaScript to change language between three or more languages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a multilingual WordPress multisite. It has more than 10 languages. I created a javascript that will redirect between 2 languages. To do that I have used `location.pathname` to get the current page URL. Then I split it to get the last directory name. I have used the if condition to check if the current URL of the page is in the second language.

For example, if I am on a page `www.xyz.com/fr/news` and then if I change the language to english. It will redirect me to `www.xyz.com/news`. Now the problem is If I add third language I am unable to figure out what condition should I use to switch between different languages. for example, If I am on a page `www.xyz.com/fr/news` and I want to switch to German. It should redirect from `www.xyz.com/fr/news` to `www.xyz.com/de/news`.

Every redirection should load the current page in requested language.

HTML Code:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" onclick="myFunction()">English</a>
```

Below is a javacript code snippet to switch from the default language.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("fr").onclick = location.replace(
        window.location.origin + "/" + fr" + "/"
    );
    document.getElementById("de").onclick = location.replace(
        window.location.origin + "/" + "de" + "/"
    );
}
```

And below is a javascript code snippet to switch from second languages to default one.

```
function myFunction() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;  
    var lang = pathname.split("/")[1];
    var page = pathname.split("/")[2];

    if ((lang = "fr/")) {
        location.replace(window.location.origin + "/" + page);
    }
}
```

Comment: To split the Pathname, you can use a single command: `let page = window.location.pathname.split("/");` This turns the URL into an Array that you can use later on with the [0], [1], etc.

Comment: @MikedeBie I have split the URL and used the parts to redirect between 2 languages. I stuck at how can I redirect when a third language is added. I am trying to add a function and if-else statement when the anchor tag is triggered by clicking but not getting the results as expected.

Comment: If you want to switch between the languages, you can us the 'Switch' statement. Use the 2 letters you get from the URL ('fr', 'en', etc.) and use those in Switch/Case statement. `case 'fr': URL = xyz.url/fr` Some explanation can be found here: (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the efficient way but have solved it.

But there is an issue with opening the link in the new tab using right-click. It shows about:blank#blocked.

I put the javascript in href of anchor tag as below.

```
<a href="javascript:eng()" class="dropdown-item" >English</a>
<a href="javascript:fre()" class="dropdown-item" >French</a>
<a href="javascript:det()" class="dropdown-item" >German</a>
```

Create separate function for each link. For example if I am on defaul page the script will be:

```
function fre() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var lang = pathname.split("/")[1];
    var page = pathname.split("/")[2];

    if (window.location.origin !== "" && lang == "") {
        window.location.replace(window.location.origin + "/fr/");
    } else {
        window.location.replace(window.location.origin + "/fr/" + lang);
    }
}
function det() {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
    var lang = pathname.split("/")[1];
    var page = pathname.split("/")[2];

    if (window.location.origin !== "" && lang == "") {
        window.location.replace(window.location.origin + "/de/");
    } else {
        window.location.replace(window.location.origin + "/de/" + lang);
    }
}
```

So the condition checks if the current window URL contains 1 or 2 directories. for example `www.xyz.com/` contains 1 which is " / " and `www.xyz.com/fr/news` contains 1 which is " fr " and 2 is " news " then redirect to the corresponding page in other languages.

Hope this will be helpful for others.

And please if there is any efficient way or improvment you are most welcome.